# Rails drop down box display values from multiple columns in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to implement a drop down box in my rails application, I would like to display data from two variables,

```
@Person.Firstname
```

and

```
@Person.Surname
```

in the box. I have the  box working with first name but I cant find any reference to how to display a second field in there. I've tried adding another argument, however that throws a too many arguments exception.
Here is the code I have for the box already:

```
<%= f.select(:evt_person, options_from_collection_for_select(Person.all, :id, :FirstName), :include_blank => true)%>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new method to your `Person` model like:

```
def fullname
  "#{FirstName} #{Surname}"
end
```

...and then use `:fullname` in `options_from_collection_for_select`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the method to my Person model, and changed the calling code, but I get this error when trying to run:  `uninitialized constant Person::Firstname`. Have I missed something?

Comment: I see now that although you have `@Person.Firstname` (with a lowercase 'n'), you also have `:FirstName` in your `f.select` line (with uppercase `N`).  I'm guessing now that `@Person.Firstname` was never actual code that you ran.  I've edited my answer to guess at what your attribute is actually called.

Comment: Ah - It would help if I copied and pasted my code rather than "paracoding" it! Thanks!